# Should I delete a copy constructor and an assignment operator of a class that internally creates threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, copy-constructor

When a class owns thread and mutex objects, are there any potential dangerous situations where a copy/assignment would be dangerous, meaning that copy constructor and assignment should be deleted?

Consider this sample code:

```
class A : B
{
    std::thread t;
    std::mutex m;

  public:
    A() : B() {}
    virtual ~A()
    {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }

    // Should I delete cctor and assignment operator?

    virtual void Method()
    {
        t = std::thread([this] 
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m);
            ... // processing
        });
    }

    // Other methods that lock on mutex m
};
```

If I understand things correctly, the thread created in `Method()` will not be visible outside of `A`, meaning that copying with a default cctor shouldn't be problematic, because the entire state would get copied. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: If copying doesn't make logical sense, then `=delete`ing the copy operations is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: They will be implicitly deleted for you as you have a `std::thread` and `std::mutex` as members.

Comment: `thread` and `mutex` already have deleted copying, so your class cannot be copied anyway. But being explicit can be good, especially if you are not sure yourself.  :-)

Comment: Thank you @RichardCritten and BoPersson, indeed this is the case, I'm sorry I missed that. If you move that to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thread deletes its copy constructor, [but not the assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D). It does not matter, though, because mutex deletes both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any class whose (extended) state includes pointers into itself must have a deleted copy/move or must marshall that state.

```
t = std::thread([this]
```

the above line stores a pointer to `this` in the class's extended state.

Default copy and move is thus inappropriate.  Deleted is one option; carefully and possibly expensively marshalling another.

In addition, both thread and mutex are move only types.  So copy will be implicitly deleted.

Your move assign/construct, however, will be written by the compiler **and wrong**.  So delete them or fix them.

---

There is a idiom from languages without class-value types (like Java/C#) of having a class with state and a thread that works on the state.  This is a bad plan in a value centric language like C++.  Store your state externally (say, a shared or unique ptr), share it with your thread (as shared ptr or as observing ptr), and suddenly default move makes sense.

Without doing that, your object becomes sessile -- unable to safely move -- which cripples a lot of great C++ idioms, or forces external smart pointer wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Both copy constructor and assign need to be deleted or defined. If you want to delete them, don't do anything: C++ will delete them for you implicitly.

Your class has `std::mutex` as a member. Its copy constructor and assignment operators are deleted. This makes C++ delete copy constructor and assignment operator of your class as well, because generating default behavior for them would require invoking deleted members.

**Note:** Deletion is not your only option: if you find it useful to make copies of `A` or make them assignable, you have an option to define a copy constructor and an assignment operator that create a new thread and a new mutex, and copy relevant parts of your object to support the semantics that you find useful. Even though C++ wouldn't do it for you by default, you have an option to do it manually.